# Measurability From countable to Uncountable sequences family of functions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I am studying Protter Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations. In a theorem on hitting times Protter has the following theorem.

Let $X$ be an adapted cadlag stochastic process, and $\Lambda$ be an open set. Then the hitting time of $\Lambda$ is a stopping time.

The proof of the theorem makes use of the fact that the hitting time defined by,

$T(\omega) = \inf \{t > 0 : X_t \in \Lambda\}$.

The proof claims $\{T(\omega) < t\} = \bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,t)} \{X_s \in \Lambda \}$

I understand that $\{x : \inf f_n(x) < \alpha \} = \bigcup_n \{x: f_n(x) < \alpha\}$ for a countable family of measurable functions $f_n$. I am not sure how we extend this idea to an uncountable family of right continuous measurable functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion
$$\{T(\omega)<t\} \supseteq \bigcup_{s\in\mathbb Q \cap [0,t)} \{X_s(\omega)\in\Lambda\}$$
holds clearly even without $\Lambda$ being open and $X$ being cadlag. For the other inclusion we need right-continuity and openess are indeed essential. If $\{T(\omega)<t\}$ for some $t$, then there is some time $s\in\mathbb R$ with $s<t$ and $X_s\in\Lambda$. As $\Lambda$ is open and $X$ right-continuous, increasing $s$ a bit does not result in $X$ leaving $\Lambda$. Hence, we find some $r\in\mathbb Q\cap [0,t)$ with $X_r\in\Lambda$. This proves the second inclusion.

Comment: Marcel, thank you for your response. I have to spend some time thinking about it.

Comment: @rk540 Your welcome. Usually, here, you should not use the comment function to say "thank you". Instead, use the up arrow on the left of an answer\comment and accept an answer (tick below down arrow) if it fits the best to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while that I posted this question. I unfortunately did not quite understand the proof on a second visit to the same question. Below is my proof. Is this right?

The proof uses the fact that the indexing set is $\mathbb{R}$. We will use also the fact that the infimum of a set is the same as the infimum of its closure and the fact that $X$ is cadlag. 
    \begin{align}
 &\inf\{ t \in \mathbb{R}^+ : X_t(\omega) \in \Lambda\} = \inf \{q \in \mathbb{Q}^+ : X_q(\omega) \in \Lambda\} \\
 &\{\omega : T(\omega) < \alpha \} = \{\omega: \inf\{t > 0, X_t(\omega) \in \Lambda \} < \alpha \}  = \{\omega: \inf\{q \in \mathbb{Q}^+, X_q(\omega) \in \Lambda \} < \alpha \}
 \end{align}

The next step is to show the following equality $$S_l = \{\omega: \inf\{q \in \mathbb{Q}^+, X_q(\omega) \in \Lambda \} < \alpha \} = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}^+ \bigcap [0,\alpha)} \{\omega: X_q(\omega) \in \Lambda \} = S_r$$
    The argument is pretty straight forward. If $\omega \in S_l$ then $q \in \mathbb{Q}^+, q < \alpha$ and $X_q(\omega) \in \Lambda \Rightarrow \omega \in S_r \Rightarrow S_l \subseteq S_r$. Similarly if $\omega \in S_r$ the same argument applies, i.e. $q \in Q^+, q < \alpha, X_q(\omega) \in \Lambda \Rightarrow S_r \subseteq S_l$.

The rest is to prove the measurability, here it is anyway.

Now that we have reduced the uncountable system of sets to a countable union, we can now apply the usual measure theoretic stuff to prove the rest. Since $X_t$ are all cadlag and adapted $\{\omega: X_t(\omega) \in \Lambda\} = \{\omega: \omega \in X_t^{-1}(\Lambda) \} \in \mathcal{F}_t$.